# Como puedo modificar una libreria en AndroidStudio

Tags: android-studio

Tengo una libreria que sirve para utilizar la descarga de informacion por json y que utiliza `AsyncTask` el problema es que quiero modificarle varios parametros pero estan bloqueados. **¿como puedo desbloquear esto?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aca te enseñan a modificar los ficheros  .class de la libreria 
http://blog.hcosta.info/modificar-ficheros-class-en-librerias-jar/

espero te sirva